# Set Project Output Directory Based on TFS Project Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 on a TFS project. I have two projects in my current project collection and one of the two projects has its workspace mapped to `C:\Workspace\ProjectA`

In this project I have one solution file with multiple .csproj files at different folder depths. What I want to do is set these .csproj projects to have their `Properties > Build > Output > Output path` property set to `C:\Workspace\ProjectA\bin\Debug` but I don't want to use a hard-coded path I want to set it like `%CurrentProjectDirectory%\bin\Debug`. Is there an easy way to do this like with some existing environment or registry variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to manage a large project. In this case, you want to have a single Common.targets file that all projects import, and then you can change such stuff by editing it directly. Put Common.targets in the root of your team project's workspace (`C:\Workspace\ProjectA`), and then import it in each .csproj by adding:

```
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)', 'Common.targets'))\Common.targets" />
```

...right before lines like `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets">`, since you want your changes to affect stuff in there.

Once you have that, you can use Common.targets to override any csproj property you want. For example, to override OutputPath, you'd have:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>My_output_path</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Note**: eventually, I found that I wanted some of the Common.targets stuff to take effect after the regular `<Import>`s. So, deleted all those `<Import>`s from all the csprojs, and moved them to Common.targets.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect, neat solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just getting around to implementing this solution now and I have a question. If Commmon.targets specifies an OutputPath will that override the .csproj OutputPath when imported?

Comment: Yes. Your property definition comes after the one in the .csproj, so it will override.

Answer (score 0):

Update the output path of all those .csproj file's by using relative file path's instead of hardcoding.

Something like ....\projectA\bin\debug ,the number of "..\" will vary depending on how the folders are structured for your individual projects.

Take a look at this article for more details: [Absolute VS Relative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)

Comment: I tried this initially by doing a Find/Replace Text on all the .csproj before I realized that some .csproj were deeper in the folder tree than others. Is there an easier way to batch edit project properties? I have over 150 .csproj files so editing each by hand isn't really going to be practical.